# Where is same origin policy in javascript implemented?

Tags: javascript, browser, same-origin-policy

How do browsers implement the same-origin policy
Can I view the source code for `XMLHttpRequest` anywhere (where do I look in v8/Spidermonkey source?)
How are javascripts sandboxed from other scripts on the same page?

Comment: V8/Spidermonkey are only JS engines and do not contain the API code of DOM and HTML5. You will need to search the Browser codebase, e.g. Webkit. Have you searched there? Also, what do you mean by "sandboxed"?

Comment: by "sandboxed" I mean
how does one <script> tag not know about the contents of another <script> tag..  i.e. how come I can do a cross-domain script request that pulls JSON data back, and other scripts not be able to modify the result of that

Comment: Well, then they're not sandboxed at all. Knowing other of script tags is done via the DOM. All scripts in a page, regardless of their origin, are executed in the same global scope. While you can *use* (execute) cross-domain external scripts, you cannot load them so that you access their source code programmatically.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, scripts loaded from another origin aren't treated any differently to local ones (except with regards to cookies set/sent in the script's request/response). If you try to load sensitive data in a script tag, it won't work because the data isn't formatted as a script.